# TypeError: next is not a function on express server

Tags: node.js, express

Currently I try to catch any errors that happen in my controller (or actually a specific endpoint being part of it) and pass them trough with next(error). Like so:

controller.js

```
exports.createTodo = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const createdTodo = await TodoModel.create(req.body);

        res.status(201).send(createdTodo);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
};
```

controller.test.js

```
let req, res, next;
beforeEach(() => {
    req = httpMocks.createRequest();
    res = httpMocks.createResponse();
    next = null;
});

    test('if the server returns an error when an invalid request is being made', async () => {
        const errorMessage = { message: 'Done property is missing' };
        const rejectedPromise = Promise.reject(errorMessage);

        TodoModel.create.mockReturnValue(rejectedPromise);
        await todoController.createTodo(req, res, next);

        expect(next).toBeCalledWith(errorMessage);
    });
```

However, the test fails and returns 'TypeError: next is not a function'. Console logging next in createTodo of the controller returns 3x undefined, 1x null and 1x [Function: next].

What causes this to happen and how can I ensure that it returns next as a function from the very beginning?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that next was assigned to null. This was part of a course I was doing, however, it should over course be something like `next = jest.fn()`